# pyqtgraph : disable vertical movement(scrolling)

Tags: graph, scroll, pyqtgraph

I am using pyqtgraph library for making my own GUI.

When I create a graph using this library, I want to lock the scrolling of vertical movement of the graph so that I can scroll the graph only the horizontal sides.

How can I do this? Is there any method to accomplish this goal?

Comment: Perhaps you can use the `setLimits` method of the viewbox to limit the axis range.

Comment: Thanks titusjan :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use `setMouseEnabled(x,y)` on the view box, e.g. `PlotWidget`. See http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/_modules/pyqtgraph/graphicsItems/ViewBox/ViewBox.html#ViewBox.setMouseEnabled

Comment: If you're dealing with a plotitem like `p = pg.PlotItem()`, then I think you want `p.setMouseEnabled(x=True, y=False)`. Depending on your specific situation, the `.getViewBox()` method might help you get something with access to the `setMouseEnabled` method.

Comment: Thank you! Your solution worked out for me too